# SoapUI comparing null from XML to null from JSON response

Tags: json, xml, groovy, null, soapui

I have a test case where I connect to database and query some data, save the result to properties then make a request to an API and compare the saved property with JSON response.

This works unless the results are null.

This is the XML result from the database.

[image]

I save the result in a script in assertion

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
def holder = new XmlHolder(messageExchange.responseContent)
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('SECONDARYPHONE', holder.getNodeValue('//*:SECONDARYPHONE'))
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('FAX', holder.getNodeValue('//*:FAX'))
```

then in JSON request to API I get

```
{
   "portalId": 87776,
   "name": "iOS Robotics",
   "address1": "Update your company address",
   "address2": "under Settings > My Company",
   "city": "Reston",
   "state": "VA",
   "zip": "20191",
   "primaryPhone": "unknown",
   "secondaryPhone": null,
   "fax": null
}
```

an in assertion step

```
import net.sf.json.groovy.JsonSlurper
def jsonResponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(messageExchange.responseContent)

log.info('Second')
log.info(context.testCase.getPropertyValue('SECONDARYPHONE'))

log.info('json')
log.info(jsonResponse.secondaryPhone)

assert jsonResponse.secondaryPhone == context.testCase.getPropertyValue('SECONDARYPHONE')
```

I get

> assert jsonResponse.secondaryPhone == context.testCase.getPropertyValue('SECONDARYPHONE') | | | | | | | | | | | null | | | | com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestCasePro@12ff4536 | | | [ThreadIndex:0, RunCount:0, ExecutionID:5cf927e7-817f-4785-9152-f35e634cfe58] | | false | net.sf.json.JSONObject@162d059c (toString() threw net.sf.json.JSONException) net.sf.json.JSONObject@2419444e (toString() threw net.sf.json.JSONException)

how can I check and compare the null values in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because, the jdbc result has `empty` value and json has `null` for the secondPhone.

So, check if jdbc result is empty for any property / attribute, then check for non equality; otherwise check for equality.

Another alternative is - in the first script, if the jdbc response value for an element is empty, then save it as `null`.

Comment: then shouldn't this work `context.testCase.setPropertyValue('SECONDARYPHONE', null)` ,  should it ? It still throws the same error. Looks like `jsonResponse.secondaryPhone` is the part that is empty,  because `context.testCase.setPropertyValue('SECONDARYPHONE', "whatever")` prints `assert jsonResponse.secondaryPhone == context.testCase.getPropertyValue('SECONDARYPHONE') | | | | | | | | | | | whatever | | | |`

Comment: So I am checking if jsonResponse.secondaryPhone is empty it fails then this passes tho `assert jsonResponse.secondaryPhone.toString() == context.testCase.getPropertyValue('SECONDARYPHONE').toString()`